# How to make a single line into two new lines

Tags: shell-script

I want to make a single line into two new lines.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="$1"

    printf "maximum file size: %s" \ 
                    find $dir -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n | tail -1
```

with the above code I am facing an probelm while generating output.

Error output:

```
maximum file size:  116864 /usr/lib/apt/methods/mirror
```

Expected output(only the path should be in a new line with one tab):

```
 maximum file size:  116864 
               /usr/lib/apt/methods/mirror
```

Comment: Do you mean `printf "maximum file size: %s\n\t\t%s\n" $(find $dir -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n | tail -1)`?

Comment: @buddha sreekanth, @Costas; Note, the `find "$dir" ...` needs quoting. (While the assignment `dir=$1` doesn't necessarily.)

Comment: @Costas No. I mean  `printf "maximum file size: %s" \ 
                    find $dir -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n | tail -1`

Comment: @buddhasreekanth It is totally wrong command and it can't produce `maximum file size:  116864 /usr/lib/apt/methods/mirror`

Comment: @Costas  Its working on my system. I checked manually via path . The command which you mentioned earlier is throwing an error as `command not found`.could you please let me know the right command.

Comment: @buddha please stop posting the same question over and over. This is the third time you have asked the same question

Comment: @roaima I am sorry, but the code which you had posted is working only for the directories. Its not showing the maximum file size in a directory with its path. `du="$(du -hba "$dir" | sort -n -r | tail -1)"
printf "size of file: %s\n\t%s\n" "${du/$'\t'*}" "${du#*$'\t'}"`

Comment: Please stop re-posting essentially the same question over and over again. Instead, edit your original question and make it clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find "$dir" -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n | tail -1 | {
    read -r size name
    printf "maximum file size: %d\n\t%s\n" "$size" "$name"
}
```

Since the `read` occurs in a subshell, I'm using braces to group the read command with the printf command. Setting the variables and using them must occur in the same subshell.

Comment: why you have written `read` and `printf` statement in braces. what does that braces do? can I write `read`statement outside the subshell?

Comment: In bash (and some other shells), each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell. If I set a variable in a subshell, that variable does not exist in the parent shell. For example: `(a=5); echo $a` prints an empty string because `a` was set in a subshell. The braces group the `read` and `printf` commands together so they are executed in the *same* subshell. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be easier to pipe the `find` output through `sed` or `awk`:

```
$!/bin/sh
dir=$1
find "$dir" -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n | tail -1 | sed -n 's/^\([0-9]\+\)\s\+\(.*\)$/Max size: \1\n\t\2/p'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
find $dir -printf "%s **\n**%p\n" | sort -n | tail -1
```

Use above command.

Comment: This will not work. The `sort` will separate the filenames from their sizes.